# Do external battery packs need to connect to ground on the arduino?

Tags: servo

I am going to be controlling 2 servo motors with an arduino. I will use an external battery pack for power. Do I need to connect the negative of the battery to ground on the arduino? If I just use the battery pack to power an LED, it works without connecting it to ground. Can someone please explain the logic behind this in simple wording? Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Ground is merely a label. It is a logical point in the circuit relative to which you measure all other voltages against.

For instance the 5V pin on the Arduino is actually 5V *relative to the ground pin*.

A 12V battery's `+` terminal is 12V *relative to the `-` terminal*. In this situation the `-` pin can be labelled Ground.

Electricity only ever flows when there is a circuit.  That is, current can only flow when it has some way of flowing back to where it came from.

A battery with an LED and resistor attached has a circuit: *Battery -> LED -> Resistor -> Battery*.  An Arduino itself is a circuit: *Power -> Arduino -> Internal Gubbins -> Power*

By the rule above, electricity can only ever flow out of an I/O pin if it has some way of getting back to where it came from. That route back is the Ground pin of the Arduino.  Interfacing some external device with the Arduino, whether it has its own power supply or not, requires that connection back to the Arduino's ground in order for the signal you send from the Arduino to have a complete circuit.

Comment: In short, always connect the grounds!

Comment: @NickGammon Unless you don't need to, such as if you have an opto-coupler.

Comment: @NickGammon so because the arduino is sending a signal to one of the pins on the servo, the servo needs to be connected to Arduino's ground. If the arduino has nothing to do with that circuit, then the negative battery terminal is enough. Is that correct? Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, the signal needs to be in reference to something. So you would have ground on the servo going to **both** the Arduino and the battery negative terminal. Then the signal from the Arduino goes to the servo control pin, and the positive side of the battery to the servo motor pin.

Answer (score 3):

I like the Majenko's answer, but I'm going to explain it with a different approach. You know that there are some quantities that are measurable in an absolute way (mass, lenght, weight) and other that need a starting point to refer. Think about the **distance**: you cannot say "New York" is distant 10km.. the question that obviously would come in mind is: 10km from what? So you have to decide a point in the world, from which you can measure the distance of every city.

The voltage measure the potential, that is the energy that a single charge would have. Now the question is: is the potential energy an absolute value? Of course not, i have to define a point where it is zero, and measure everything from it. In a circuit this point is called Ground, evry potential measured in the circuit is calculated to the ground.

The last step is to know that charges goes from the points at higher pot to the lowest one (the ground), usually preferring the path with lower resistsnce (but that's another story). **A wire has the same potential all along it** and in order to compare the voltage of arduino and the battery pack they must refer to the same ground.

Answer (score 2):

> so because the arduino is sending a signal to one of the pins on the servo, the servo needs to be connected to Arduino's ground.

Here is typically how you might wire a servo:

[image: Servo wiring]

Note the shared ground. The Arduino provides the control signal (data) via the orange wire. The battery provides the motor power via the red wire. The grounds must be shared or the voltages on each wire are meaningless.